# Getting errors when trying to sign in using Intent

Tags: java, android-studio, android-xml

Here I am having simple login by intent, I get some error I stated my error below with my coding, I would like to know my mistake and answer to rectify an error! I didn't finish; I'm just checking whether value passes from Signup.class to Register.class here itself got so many errors.

```
public class Signup extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.signup);

        String firstName, lastName, mobile, password, email;
        EditText edt_Signup_FirstName, edt_Signup_LastName, edt_Signup_Mobile, edt_Signup_Password, edt_Signup_Email;
        Button btn_Signup_Register;

        edt_Signup_FirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_first_name);
        edt_Signup_LastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_last_name);
        edt_Signup_Mobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_mobile);
        edt_Signup_Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_password);
        edt_Signup_Email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_email);

        btn_Signup_Register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signup_register);

        btn_Signup_Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Signup.this, Register.class);
                startActivity(i);

                firstName = edt_Signup_FirstName.getText().toString();
                lastName = edt_Signup_LastName.getText().toString();
                mobile = edt_Signup_Mobile.getText().toString();
                int conversion = Integer.parseInt(mobile);
                password = edt_Signup_Password.getText().toString();
                email = edt_Signup_Email.getText().toString();

                i.putExtra("key_f", firstName);
                i.putExtra("key_l", lastName);
                i.putExtra("key_m", mobile);
                i.putExtra("key_p", password);
                i.putExtra("key_e", email);

            }
        });
    }
}

public class Register extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        TextView txt_FirstName, txt_LastName, txt_Mobile, txt_Password, txt_Email;

        txt_Email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_email);
        txt_FirstName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_firstName);
        txt_LastName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_lastName);
        txt_Mobile = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_mobile);
        txt_Password = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        String firstname = i.getStringExtra("key_f");
        String lastname = i.getStringExtra("key_l");
        String mobile = i.getStringExtra("key_m");
        String password = i.getStringExtra("key_p");
        String email = i.getStringExtra("key_e");

        txt_Email.setText("EMAIL : " + email);
        txt_FirstName.setText("FIRSTNAME : " + firstname);
        txt_LastName.setText("LASTNAME : " + lastname);
        txt_Mobile.setText("MOBILE : " + mobile);
        txt_Password.setText("PASSWORD : " + password);
    }
}
```

Errors:

```
Error:(41, 50) error: variable mobile might not have been initialized
Error:(45, 36) error: variable firstName might not have been initialized
Error:(46, 36) error: variable lastName might not have been initialized
Error:(48, 36) error: variable password might not have been initialized
Error:(49, 36) error: variable email might not have been initialized
Error:(38, 29) error: local variable edt_Signup_FirstName is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
Error:(38, 17) error: local variable firstName is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
Error:(39, 28) error: local variable edt_Signup_LastName is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
Error:(39, 17) error: local variable lastName is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
Error:(40, 26) error: local variable edt_Signup_Mobile is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
Error:(40, 17) error: local variable mobile is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
Error:(42, 28) error: local variable edt_Signup_Password is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
Error:(42, 17) error: local variable password is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final 
Error:(43, 25) error: local variable edt_Signup_Email is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final 
Error:(43, 17) error: local variable email is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final 
Error:(47, 36) error: local variable mobile is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

    Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Where? Post the stack trace. It also looks like you start the activity before you pass in your extras.

Comment: How about "needs to be declared final"?

Answer (score 1):

make variables final (in this line )

```
    String firstName,lastName,mobile,password,email;
```

replace it by

```
final String firstName ;
final String lastName;
```

make all of them like this

then make all of (EditText) (final)
for example :

```
final edt_Signup_Email ;
```

it will work for sure

Comment: Error:(41, 50) error: variable mobile might not have been initialized
like these i get for all variables when i compile it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post your stacktrace. You do start the activity before passing in your extras though, so try replacing this:

```
btn_Signup_Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i =new Intent(Signup.this,Register.class);
        startActivity(i);

        firstName = edt_Signup_FirstName.getText().toString();
        lastName = edt_Signup_LastName.getText().toString();
        mobile = edt_Signup_Mobile.getText().toString();
        int conversion =Integer.parseInt(mobile);
        password = edt_Signup_Password.getText().toString();
        email = edt_Signup_Email.getText().toString();

        i.putExtra("key_f",firstName);
        i.putExtra("key_l",lastName);
        i.putExtra("key_m",mobile);
        i.putExtra("key_p",password);
        i.putExtra("key_e",email);

    }
});
```

With:

```
btn_Signup_Register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i =new Intent(Signup.this,Register.class);


        firstName = edt_Signup_FirstName.getText().toString();
        lastName = edt_Signup_LastName.getText().toString();
        mobile = edt_Signup_Mobile.getText().toString();
        int conversion =Integer.parseInt(mobile);
        password = edt_Signup_Password.getText().toString();
        email = edt_Signup_Email.getText().toString();

        i.putExtra("key_f",firstName);
        i.putExtra("key_l",lastName);
        i.putExtra("key_m",mobile);
        i.putExtra("key_p",password);
        i.putExtra("key_e",email);

        startActivity(i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

These declarations:

```
String firstName, lastName, mobile, password, email;
```

must be moved into the method where the variables are used:

```
String firstName = edt_Signup_FirstName.getText().toString();
String lastName = edt_Signup_LastName.getText().toString();
String mobile = edt_Signup_Mobile.getText().toString();
int conversion = Integer.parseInt(mobile);
String password = edt_Signup_Password.getText().toString();
String email = edt_Signup_Email.getText().toString();
```

And all the Variables edt_*, e.g.:

```
EditText edt_Signup_FirstName
```

should be declared final:

```
final EditText edt_Signup_FirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edt_signup_first_name);
```